# Integrating html2canvas with jspdf

Tags: angularjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I have an angularjs project where I've created a module that uses html2canvas to capture images.  I also have a module that generates PDF's using jspdf.

I've gotten them working together somewhat, however, the issue is with the html2canvas `onrendered`.  The image isn't available till `onrendered` has been called, so jspdf technically needs to wait till it's ready.

My pdf module just puts items into an object as the methods are called and then builds the pdf.

Ideally, I don't want to put jspdf code into my `onrendered` - since they are different modules anyway.

What would be a good approach in this case - promises, passing in a callback to my html2canvas, something else?